# Returning array of historical prices from yahoo finance API in apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, yahoo-finance

I'm trying to get historical prices for a number of tickers in my google sheets by creating a custom function. The below code seems to run fine in apps script, but it doesn't output anything in my spreadsheet, just giving the error #NUM! The result was not a number. Obviously I need to turn this into an array, but I'm not sure how to do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 /**
 * Fetch historical prices from Yahoo Finance
 * 
 * @param ticker The ticker to fetch historical prices for, e.g. "AAPL"
 * @param range The range to return (e.g. "1y")
 * @param interval e.g. "1d"
 * @param metrics e.g. "Close"
 * @customfunction
 */

function YFHistorical(ticker, range, interval, metrics) {
  var ticker = ticker || "GOOG";
  var range = range || "1y";
  var interval = interval || "1d";
  var metrics = metrics || "close";
  var uri = ("https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/" + ticker + "?metrics=" + metrics + "&interval=" + interval + "&range=" + range);
 
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(uri);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  var data2 = data.chart.result[0].indicators.quote;
  return parseFloat(data2);
}
```

Comment: If you mean to get an array why do you use `parseFloat()` method? This is Number's method, not Array's. How the desired output should look like? One number or a column of numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a guess... try to change the lines:

```
var data2 = data.chart.result[0].indicators.quote;
return parseFloat(data2);
```

to:

```
var data2 = data.chart.result[0].indicators.quote[0].high;
return data2;
```

But actually the object `data.chart.result[0].indicators.quote[0]` has five 'keys':

```
{'low':[], 'high':[], 'open':[], 'close':[], 'volume':[]}
```

Each 'key' contains an array of numbers. It's not clear which of the arrays you want to get. Or do you want to get all the arrays (five columns? five rows?)?

**Update**

Next guess:

```
function YFHistorical(ticker, range, interval, metrics) {
  var ticker = ticker || "GOOG";
  var range = range || "1y";
  var interval = interval || "1d";
  var metrics = metrics || "close";
  var uri = ("https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/" + ticker + "?metrics=" + metrics + "&interval=" + interval + "&range=" + range);
 
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(uri);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  var high = data.chart.result[0].indicators.quote[0].high;
  var low = data.chart.result[0].indicators.quote[0].low;
  var timestamps = data.chart.result[0].timestamp.map(t => new Date(t * 1000));
  var header = ['Timestamps', 'High', 'Low']
  var table = [header, ...timestamps.map((t, i) => [t, high[i], low[i]])];
  return table;
}
```

It returns two of the arrays (the keys 'high' and 'low') with timestamps, makes the header, and return it as an array.

Result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'm very inexperienced with this, so it's very appreciated. Yuri's answer helped me solve it. As an addon-question, how can I also get the dates in the column prior to this data and the headers for both? I guess I would have to use the timestamp from the API, but that seems to be UNIX formatted.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the addon-question. Dates from the API? Could you show how your request looks like? Basically you can convert `unix_timestamp` into a `date` object this way: `var date = new Date(unix_timestamp * 1000);` But the rest: get the array of timestamps, convert them into dates, add header and put everything on a -- it needs more details

Comment: The sample URL is https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/GOOG?interval=1d&range=1y. My end goal is to get 2 columns showing "Date" and "Close" as headers and then populating the rest of the cells with the corresponding dates and closing prices. I tried adding the below for converting the timestamps, but I'm missing something. Not sure how to go on with the headers either.


`var timestamp = data.chart.result[0].timestamp;
  
    for (let i = 0; i < timestamp.length; i++) {
      var date = new Date(timestamp * 1000);
  }`

Comment: Well. I tried to do it. See my update. But I still don't know which of those five arrays you're looking for.